# Merging 3 layers, but name the new merged layer as a combination of the 3 layers merged

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I don't even know if this is possible but i hope it is.
Photoshop CS6
So i have 3 layers
01
02
03
i want to select them all and merge them,
but i want that merged layer to be named 01,02,03

Is this possible?
the layer names will be different every time also.
Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to do this automatically? Because the easiest answer I can give you is to merge them then simply rename the new layer.

Comment: It's possible with a script.